# Cython_freeze with crosscompile produces ctypes import error

Tags: python, cython, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile a Python application with cython and cython_freeze.
Host is UBUNTU 17.04 x64. target is Raspberry Pi UBUNTU MATE 16.04 (gnueabihf).

The compilation works, but at runtime, when ctypes is imported in the application, an ImportError occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cttest.py", line 1, in init cttest
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-36m-armlinux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: _PyUnicode_AsWideCharString
```

What' wrong?

(If do the compilation on the target, everything works).

Compile:

```
python3.6 cython_freeze -o ctmain.c cttest

arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -fPIC -O2 -Wall -Wextra -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv  -I/root/eabi-chroot/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c -o ctmain.o ctmain.c

python3.6 -m cython cttest

arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -fPIC -O2 -Wall -Wextra -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv  -I/root/eabi-chroot/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c -o cttest.o cttest.c

arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -Xlinker -export-dynamic -L/root/eabi-chroot/usr/local/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-arm-linux-gnueabihf ctmain.o cttest.o -lpython3.6m -lm -lpthread -ldl -lutil -o ctmain
```

Python File (cttest.py):

```
import ctypes

def main():
    print("OK")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

NB: The actual environment is far more complicated (and the ctypes imports are  are in various 3rd party libraries).

Excerpt of cross compiled loader debug output:

```
4154:   symbol=_PyUnicode_AsWideCharString;  lookup in file=./ctmain [0]
  4154: symbol=_PyUnicode_AsWideCharString;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so [0]
  4154: symbol=_PyUnicode_AsWideCharString;  lookup in file=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 [0]
  4154: symbol=_PyUnicode_AsWideCharString;  lookup in file=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 [0]
  4154: symbol=_PyUnicode_AsWideCharString;  lookup in file=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 [0]
  4154: symbol=_PyUnicode_AsWideCharString;  lookup in file=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libutil.so.1 [0]
  4154: symbol=_PyUnicode_AsWideCharString;  lookup in file=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 [0]
  4154: symbol=_PyUnicode_AsWideCharString;  lookup in file=/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 [0]
  4154: symbol=_PyUnicode_AsWideCharString;  lookup in file=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-36m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so [0]
  4154: symbol=_PyUnicode_AsWideCharString;  lookup in file=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 [0]
  4154: symbol=_PyUnicode_AsWideCharString;  lookup in file=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 [0]
  4154: symbol=_PyUnicode_AsWideCharString;  lookup in file=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 [0]
  4154: symbol=_PyUnicode_AsWideCharString;  lookup in file=/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 [0]
  4154: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-36m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _PyUnicode_AsWideCharString (fatal)
  4154: 
  4154: file=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-36m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so [0];  destroying link map
  4154: 
  4154: file=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 [0];  destroying link map
```

Excerpt of local compiled loder debug output:

```
  4124: symbol=PyUnicode_AsWideChar;  lookup in file=./cttest [0]
  4124: symbol=_ctypes_simple_instance;  lookup in file=./cttest [0]
  4124: symbol=_ctypes_simple_instance;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so [0]
  4124: symbol=_ctypes_simple_instance;  lookup in file=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 [0]
  4124: symbol=_ctypes_simple_instance;  lookup in file=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 [0]
  4124: symbol=_ctypes_simple_instance;  lookup in file=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 [0]
  4124: symbol=_ctypes_simple_instance;  lookup in file=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libutil.so.1 [0]
  4124: symbol=_ctypes_simple_instance;  lookup in file=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 [0]
  4124: symbol=_ctypes_simple_instance;  lookup in file=/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 [0]
  4124: symbol=_ctypes_simple_instance;  lookup in file=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-36m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so [0]
```

Comment: To me it looks like not all needed shared libraries can be found.

Comment: When I do the build on the RPi the resulting programs runs without error.

Comment: Start both versions of your program with `LD_DEBUG=libs,files,symbols <your program>` and see the difference. Probably different rpaths.

Comment: I have both of the files. They are different in  many places, but the libraries searched for PyUnicode_AsWideChar (see edited issue)

Comment: They are different symbols...

Comment: You are right. And I also have reason for that. The crosscompile machine had 2 different chroot environments (one "original environment" and one that was updates with the target. The compile was using the original environement.